# Total number of ways of selecting two numbers from the set {1,2,3,4,5..........,3n} so that their sum is divisible by 3 is S. Find S?

Tags: combinatorics

Total number of ways of selecting two numbers from the set $\{ 1,2,3,4,5..........,3n \}$ so that their sum is divisible by $3$ is $S$. Find $S$?

This question came in my test and we were supposed to do it in less than $3$ minutes. I still can't get the answer

Comment: Question: are the selected numbers allowed to be equal? Hint: if one number has been selected then how many possibilities are left for the second number?

Comment: The numbers can't be repeated like 3,3 or 6,6

Comment: Can you solve it for $n=1$, Nipun? for $n=2$? $n=3$? maybe seeing how those cases work out will give you the idea for the general case.

Comment: I tried replacing values for n and found the general case in the test after finding upto n=4 but I couldn't prove it for all natural number

Comment: Gerry myerson I got the idea of using induction now , first find the general case by putting values of n and then prove it by induction to be true

Comment: @NipunWahi I would not use induction here. Finding the general case asks for a reasoning that is sufficient as answer.

Comment: I know that there should be some other method to find that but I still can't get an answer without putting values and then using induction to prove that

Comment: For n=1 there is only one pair 1+2=3 and for n=2 its 5 solutions 1+2,1+5,2+4,3+6,4+5 and n=3 there are similarly 12 solutions,I noticed that there differences are in arithmetic progression and then found the answers to be (3n²-n)/2 and then proved by induction

Comment: Well done. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment addressed to me, you have to put @Gerry in it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first number is divisible by $3$, then so is the other one; we choose two multiples of $3$ out of $n$, total ${n\choose 2}$ possibilities.

If the first number (say, $n$) is not divisible by $3$, then the remainder of the second number ($m$) by division by $3$ is different. So either $n$ or $m$ is $1\mod 3$ and the other $2\mod 3$. Since order isn't relevant, we can assume $n\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $m\equiv 2\mod 3$, so that we have ${n\choose 1}{n\choose 1}$ possibilities.

Thus,

$$S={n\choose 2}+{n\choose 1}{n\choose 1}=\frac12n\left(3n-1\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: there are two different cases, so try to calculate how many ways there are for each case separately, and add. The two cases are:

1. choose two multiples of $3$;
2. choose one number which leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $3$, and one number which leaves remainder $2$.

Comment: I tried your method and got stuck in the midway